# /setblock a command block with nearest player's name inside

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using a mod with the custom map I am making.  The mod adds some commands, but they are far from perfect.  For example, the command syntax goes like this:

```
/modcommand foo <PlayerName> DoThis
```

In a command block I put

```
/modcommand foo feldspar15523 DoThis
```

And everything works as expected.  However, if I do this:

```
/modcommand foo @p DoThis
```

The mod thinks that the player's name is literally `@p`.  My idea was to make it so that when I trigger the block, it first makes another Command Block that has the name of the nearest player in it in the right place.  Here is what I need in pseudocode:

```
/setblock ~ ~+5 ~ minecraft:chain_command_block 1 replace {Command:"/modcommand foo "+ @p +" DoThis"}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. Minecraft doesn't have variables like strings. The best you can do is to output the command in chat, like this:

```
/tellraw @s [{"text":"/setblock ~ ~5 ~ chain_command_block 1 replace {Command:\"modcommand foo "},{"selector":"@p"},{"text":" DoThis\"}"}]
```

If you have the log output open, you can then copy the command into chat and run it. A modded client could also automatically execute it, but not a regular Vanilla client.

Comment: I think I got it.  Would it work to place a sign that has that command with the name in it and have the user run the command on right click?

Comment: Before I wrote that answer, I tried to put together a clickEvent with a selector in it in `tellraw`, but sadly the `value` of that only allows a single string, not another JSON object. And if it was possible, people would certainly already abuse it to no end. :D

Comment: I am making a custom altar that runs the command from the mod.  The command is only supposed to be for cheating, but I am making an altar that runs the command.  Selectors don't work in the cheat command.  What would work is have the trigger from the altar trigger a command block that places a sign that runs two commands on click: `/modcommand foo <Nearest player's name> DoThis` and `/setblock ~ ~ ~ air`.  I am sorry I was not very clear.

Comment: Your initial question was clearer than that comment. What mod?

Comment: Avatar mod 2:https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/avatar-mod-2-out-of-the-iceberg  The exact command is `/avatar bending add <Name> all`.

Comment: You should report that as a bug. I see no reason why it shouldn't allow selectors.